# Can Microsoft's cognitive service find similar person in a set of images without using the face service?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-recognition, cognitive-science

I need to create an application that can detect if a person X entered as an input exists in an image set and return as output all the images in which the person X exists. The problem is that the pictures do not only contain people's faces, they also contain pictures taken from behind.

Is it possible to use [Microsoft's cognitive services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/)? If not, is there another solution to allow the realization of this application?